# How to manipulate pointers of a vector?

Tags: c++

```
vector <int> *a;

a->push_back(10);

*a[0] = (*a[0])%5;
```

But this gives me an error. On the last line. Why?
I did it correctly right?

I dereferenced a, then accesses item [0], the modulus it.

```
Error: no match for 'operator*' in '** a'
```

Comment: You haven't allocated a vector. Try `vector<int>* a = new vector<int>`. (if you're getting compiler errors than this isn't your current problem, but will become one when you try to execute)

Comment: Try this (*a)[0] = ((*a)[0])%5; to avoid the compilation arrow.

Comment: `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 6):

First, if you ***need*** to use this as pointer, you must allocate memory for this `vector`, like

```
vector <int> *a = new vector <int>;
```

I highly recommend you to use

```
vector <int> a;
```

instead, if possible.

---

Also, note [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) - `operator[]` has higher priority than `*`.

Try

```
(*a)[0] = (*a)[0]%5;
```

(meaning: `*a[0]` is the same as `*(a[0])`, which you don't want)

Comment: Correct. Or, if you really need pointers, either use a vector of pointers (can be tricky): `std::vector<int*> a;` or don't use the STL: `int **a;`. I prefer the latter for speed, but the STL can make everything so much easier: Try not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than unary `*`, so it's parsed as `*(a[0])` rather than `(*a)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(*a)[ 0 ]`
2. `a->at( 0 )` <-- IMHO it's better. `at` checks vector's boundaries, but `[]` doesn't

Comment: "it's better" there's no "better" in general. Depends on the case. Otherwise, you wouldn't have 2 ways to access the same thing.

Comment: @KirilKirov you're right, but as I can see - OP is a junior in C++ and it would be better for him to use checkable version.

Comment: I'd disagree. If OP knows for sure, the index will be valid (for example, `for` loop without changing the size of the vector), no need to use `at`. I don't believe it's a good idea to learn things the not-so-good-way, and later to try to fix things. But just my opinion, of course.